# Fill different data of the same form multiple times and auto submit to google sheet

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-sheets

I have one some data need transfer to array, and send it to google sheet
Data look like below
-|PO: 2005 |
12121211212121,| Qty: 45|
BIN:110|
eBay| 11/6/2017-|
PO: 2165 |
333333333,| Qty: 54|
BIN:20|
google| 11/6/2017-|

First I user JS transfer to array, and I put all data from array to form, and click submit form.

Array like

(6) ["PO: 2005 ", " 12121211212121,", " Qty: 45", " BIN:110", " eBay", " 11/6/2017"]
index.html:62 
(6) [" PO: 2165 ", " 333333333,", " Qty: 54", " BIN:20", " google", " 11/6/2017"]

The form should be submitted multiple times, but on the google sheet I only got the data for the first one

This is my main HTML

```js
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

//  
$(document).ready(function() {
    //
    $('#googleSheetInsert').bootstrapValidator({
        //submitButtons: '#postForm',
        // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },  
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        // Get the BootstrapValidator instance
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        var url = ' ';
        var redirectUrl = 'index.html';
        // show the loading 
        $('#postForm').prepend($('<span></span>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate'));
        var jqxhr = $.post(url, $form.serialize(), function(data) {
            console.log("Success! Data: " + data.statusText);
           // $(location).attr('href',redirectUrl); relocation
        })
            .fail(function(data) {
                console.warn("Error! Data: " + data.statusText);
                // HACK - check if browser is Safari - and redirect even if fail b/c we know the form submits.
                if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
                    //alert("Browser is Safari -- we get an error, but the form still submits -- continue.");
                    $(location).attr('href',redirectUrl);                
                }
            });
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #container {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    </style>
    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
    -->
<script>
        
        function submitDataToGoogleSheet(){
            var dataFromInput = document.getElementById("SOS_POData").value;
            // Split by -| and put to array
            var filter0 = dataFromInput.split("-|");
            // Remove Empty Element
            var unitArray =[]; 
            for(var i=0;i<filter0.length;i++){
                if(filter0[i]!==""){
                    unitArray.push(filter0[i].split("|")); 
                }
            }
            // insert data to google sheet
            
            for(j=0;j<unitArray.length;j++){
            doSubmite(unitArray,j);
            }
         
        }
        
        function doSubmite(unitArray,j){
            console.log(unitArray[j]);
            document.getElementById('PO_Number').value = ((unitArray[j][0]).substring(4)).replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
            document.getElementById('Part_Number').value = (unitArray[j][1]).replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
            document.getElementById('Qty').value = ((unitArray[j][2]).substring(5)).replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
            document.getElementById('BIN').value = (unitArray[j][3]).substring(5);
            document.getElementById('Receiver_Name').value = (unitArray[j][4]).replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
            document.getElementById('Receiver_Data').value = (unitArray[j][5]).replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,"");
            document.getElementById('postForm').click();
            
            
        }
         
          
    
        
        
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Please copy all information from laeb in there.</h1>
    <div id="container">
      
      <form id="dataFromSOS" action="#" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="SOS_POData" id="SOS_POData" required="" placeholder="Please copy all label information in there">
          <input type="button" name="submit_form" value="Submite" onclick="submitDataToGoogleSheet()"> 
      </form >
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <form id="googleSheetInsert">
            <label>PO</label>
            <input id='PO_Number' name='PO_Number' type='text'>  
            <label>PartNumber</label>
            <input id='Part_Number' name='Part_Number' type='text'>
            <label>Qty</label>
            <input id='Qty' name='Qty' type='text'>
            <label>BIN</label>
            <input id='BIN' name='BIN' type='text'>
            <label>Receiver_Name</label>
            <input id='Receiver_Name' name='Receiver_Name' type='text'>
            <label>Receiver_Data</label>
            <input id='Receiver_Data' name='Receiver_Data' type='text'>
            <input type="submit"   name="submit" id="postForm"  />
        </form>
        
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/sendDataToGoogleSheedAjax.js"></script>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the Google Sheet to handle your forms being submitted at the same time?

You might follow the below example:
https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

As far as your multiple submits, they seem to be working as far as I can tell (without a sheet to submit to). If I step through the code I can see the form being updated with the values and everything seems parsed okay. Which is what leaves me to believe the problem is on the receiving side.

To get it to work for me I did the following:

1. Have your names in the google sheet columns and form `<input name="">` match.
2. In your google sheets go to Tools->Script editor and insert the script from here: https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293
3. In the script editor Do Run->Run Function->setup
4. In the script editor Do Publish->Deploy as web app...

   - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
   - Be sure to note the url as that's what we will POST to
   - It should look like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/<GIBERISH>/exec`
5. Update how you call the ajax POST function (I couldn't get the bootstrap validator to work. In fact it was causing only 1 POST to be sent, so I just removed it and everything functions as expected.)

Code:

```
$('#googleSheetInsert').on('submit', function(e) {
      // Prevent form submission
      e.preventDefault();

      // Get the form instance
      var $form = $(e.target);

      // Use Ajax to submit form data
      var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/<GIBERISH>/exec';
      var redirectUrl = 'index.html';
      // show the loading 
      $('#postForm').prepend($('<span></span>').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate'));
      var jqxhr = $.post(url, $form.serialize(), function(data) {
          console.log("Success! Data: " + data.statusText);
        // $(location).attr('href',redirectUrl); relocation
      })
          .fail(function(data) {
              console.warn("Error! Data: " + data.statusText);
              // HACK - check if browser is Safari - and redirect even if fail b/c we know the form submits.
              if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
                  //alert("Browser is Safari -- we get an error, but the form still submits -- continue.");
                  $(location).attr('href',redirectUrl);                
              }
          });
  });
```

Images Showing the working code:

[Submitting your test data a couple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQdvc.png)
[Form updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcOdC.png)

Comment: Thank you, I try that instructions, But I got a lot of error.

Comment: Can you specify because I did manage to get it working (in chrome anyway).